# Details of attack mechanics and hero figures

Tags: dota-2

[Abbadon](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon) has 0.68 attacks per second, a base attack time of 1.7 and attack duration of 0.56+0.41. How is 0.56+0.41 related to 0.68 or 1.7 and what happens when in the course of say 2 attacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Definition and formulas

- Base attack time (BAT) is the base time a hero takes between each attacks. This value can NOT change (its the Attack Time your hero is "born with" if you will) except with some skills (Alchemist's Rage for example)
- 0.56 + 0.41 is the Attack Point + Backswing Time : From the moment Abbadon start an attack, it takes 0.56 sec to reach the point where Abbadon actually deals damage. Then it take 0.41 sec for him to go back to neutral position. Those 0.41 sec can be [animation canceled](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130145/how-does-animation-canceling-work-is-it-a-valid-technique/130159#130159)
- The Attack Per Second  (APS) depends on the hero BAT and his Increased Attack Speed (IAS). IAS can be found on items, skills and with agility (1 agility = +1%IAS). It is calculated as follow (Note that IAS is % based so +100% in IAS mean +1 in formula : you have to divide the IAS % by 100) :

*APS = (1+IAS)/BAT ==> The more you have IAS, the more Attack Per Second you can perform*

### Abaddon Example

Abaddon has a 1.7 sec BAT and starts with 17 agility which means +17% IAS (or +0.17) which gives us (1+0.17)/1.7 = 1.17/1.7 = 0.68822... which is truncated to 0.68 APS.

### Increasing your Attack Time

Your BAT can't change, however your  Attack Time (AT) can decrease (= you can perform an attack more frequently) if you put enough IAS on your hero :

*AT = BAT/(1+IAS) ==> The more IAS, the lower Attack Time*

### Evolution of Attack Point and Attack Backswing

Not only your AT is impacted by IAS but also your Attack Point and your Attack Backswing. Those stats are calculated as follow :

- *Attack Point = (Base Attack Point) / (1 + IAS)*
- *Backswing Time = (Base Backswing Time) / (1 + IAS)*

*==> The more IAS, the fastest is the animation*

### More on the wiki

- [On Attack Animation](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Attack_animation)
- [On Attack Speed in general](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Attack_speed)

Comment: The main point of my question is the following: Attack Point and Backswing Time seem to be fixed. Attack Time decreases with higher IAS. Attack Point and Backswing Time should decrease as well. With IAS>233 the Attack Time will be lower than the Attack Point. And the second part of the answer is probably this: T=0s: Attack started, T=0.56s: Damage dealt, T=1.47s (AT): Attack started, T=1.47s+0.56s: Damage dealt.

Comment: @Konsta updated my answer

Comment: At point 2, the "animation canceled" part, isn't the first part (0.56)?

Comment: @zozo you can cancel at any time but you want to cancel the 0.41s of the backswing time which correspond to the animation of "going back to neutral position after the attack". If you cancel before you won't hit the target which seems quite pointless

Comment: Is not pointless. I can give you n reasons when you want to cancel b4 hitting (blademail, last hitting, etc.). Still I didn't know you can "skip" the 0.41 so I can say I learned something +1.