# How to stop Meepo's Poof?

Tags: dota-2

Watching Dota 2 videos I keep seeing people starting Poof with Meepo and then stopping it. For example, [this video](http://youtu.be/YezbD012jLk?t=164s) (at 2:45):

How to do it?

I tried to right click elsewhere, tried to press "Esc". This doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to press the *stop* key that can be configured in the setting menu. As mentionned by [TankorSmash](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185728/how-to-stop-meepos-poof/185733#comment251872_185733), pressing the stop key is always used to perform an [animation cancel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130145/how-does-animation-canceling-work-is-it-a-valid-technique/130159#130159) with skills that have non-zero cast time.

Comment: Note that this applies to literally every skill and ability that has a non-zero cast time.

Comment: The stop key is `s` by default

Answer (score 3):

The stop key is S by default, but yeah, can be changed in the settings. This will also stop you from autoattacking or doing anything else and literally just stops your character from moving or doing anything.