# Nature's Prophet Teleportation skill interrupted from a stun from jungle creep - how?

Tags: dota-2

I know that the Teleportation skill of Nature's Prophet isn't channeling spell, so it can't be interrupted.

But in [this](https://youtu.be/DneIMVKzhhE?t=38m40s) game between Alliance and Na'Vi, a neutral jungle creep interrupted this spell.

How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct that Teleportation isn't channeling. However, it is interruptible.

It has a custom 'cast point', which in this case is 3 seconds. Every spell has a cast point (sometimes it's 0), and if spells are interrupted or cancelled prior to the cast point, they don't go on cooldown. This is the same concept behind stop cancelling a spell that you decide you don't want to cast.

Comment: So *any* skill can be interrupted if the animation is interrupted before the 'cast point', am I correct?

Comment: @iamcreasy Before the end of the cast point, yes.

Comment: As an example, you can stun Spirit Breaker while he's casting his ult, and he'll still cast it again afterwards. The difference with a channeled spell is that the caster continues to cast it after the cast point, and it goes on cooldown immediately at the cast point.

Comment: Do items have cast point?

Comment: @iamcreasy No, but they require you to be facing towards the target to use them, so they're not always instantaneous.

Comment: TP scroll takes time, but Blink Dagger doesn't. I don't know if Black King Bar takes time or not. Does BKB has a cast point?

Comment: @iamcreasy TP Scroll is channeled. That's different from a cast point. No items have cast points.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed Teleportation is not a channeling however its cast point is very late. This means that there is a noticable period (with an animation) between the moment you start the spell and the moment where the spell is actually casted (when the mana is spent and when Nature's Prophet teleports). This animation can be [manually canceled](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130145/how-does-animation-canceling-work-is-it-a-valid-technique) or interrupted by a disable.  In this situation, you can see the Centaur use [War Stomp](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Centaur_Camp#War_Stomp) which is an AOE stun thus canceling the spell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about that sec(38.42) where a jungle creep hit np when he was channelling then let me tell you that channelling spell will be finished if you will stun them and that's what that creep did..he uses his first ulti to stun them and because of that tp got cancelled.